# How do you make a button show a + (plus sign) when not clicked, and - (minus sign) when clicked?

Tags: reactjs, button, onclick, toggle, onchange

Please see code below.

```
const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

const toggleExpanded = () => setExpanded(!expanded);

<button className="plus" onClick={toggleExpanded}> + </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-dhawan-1z3dbx?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
function main () {
  const [Sign, setSign] = useState('+')
  function handleClick () {
    if (Sign === '+') setSign('-')
    else setSign('+')
  }
  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{Sign}</button>
}
```